# packages.lock.json contains version information for ProjectReferences that break the workflow

Tags: .net, nuget, version, restore

I have a solution with 100+ projects having multi-layer dependencies between each other.
Once I create packages.lock.json using `dotnet restore --force-evaluate` I'm getting files that contain my `ProjectReference`s with version information.
The problem is that projects in the solution have their versions calculated based on rules and each build both locally and on build agents gets a new version making my lock files inconsistent with reality.

Here is a simplified project setup:

```
MySolution.sln
  - A.csproj
    - Dependencies:
      - Packages:
        - PackageA ver 1.2.3 (expressed as <PackageReference Include="PackageA" Version="1.2.3" />)
      - Projects:
        - B.csproj (expressed as <ProjectReference Include="..\B\B.csproj" />)
  - B.csproj
    - Dependencies:
      - Projects:
        - Utility.csproj (expressed as <ProjectReference Include="..\Utility\Utility.csproj" />)
  - Utility.csproj
    - Dependencies:
      - PackageB ver 3.2.3 (expressed as <PackageReference Include="PackageB" Version="3.2.3" />)
```

After running `dotnet restore --force-evaluate` on the solution folder for first time I get 3 new packages.lock.json files one in each project folder.
The problematic one is the one for project `A`:

```json
{
    "version": 1,
    "dependencies": {
        ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2": {
            "PackageA ": {
                "type": "Direct",
                "requested": "[1.2.3, )",
                "resolved": "1.2.3",
                "contentHash": "some-package-hash-value",
                "dependencies": {
                    "some-dependency": "[3.3.0]"
                }
            },
            "B": {
                "type": "Project",
                "dependencies": {
                    "Utility": "1.0.22"
                }
            },
            "Utility": {
                "type": "Project",
                "dependencies": {
                    "PackageB": "3.2.3"
                }
            },
            "PackageB": {
                "type": "Transitive",
                "resolved": "3.2.3",
                "contentHash": "some-package-hash-value-2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is the version of the `Utility` project dependency in `B` as it will change for each build.
I am using:

- `dotnet` version 5.0.301
- SDK-style .csproj files targeting .Net Framework 4.7.2
- PackageReference syntax for Nuget package references

Error that I am getting during `dotnet restore --locked-mode` on build agent:

```
error NU1004: The packages lock file is inconsistent with the project dependencies so restore can't be run in locked mode. Disable the RestoreLockedMode MSBuild property or pass an explicit --force-evaluate option to run restore to update the lock file. 
  Failed to restore A.csproj.
```

**1. Is there a way to exclude Project references from the `packages.lock.json` file?**
**2. Is this the expected and correct behavior when producing `packages.lock.json` files?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I believe this is the way that lock files are meant to work. They ensure that the dependencies used in the locked-mode restore are *exactly* the same as the dependencies specified in the lock file (not juist the version number but the actual file content too).

The solutions I see for you are:

1. don't use a lock file for anything referencing Utility.csproj - you want this reference to be dynamic so you need to ensure that the version number is the same
2. Change the rules such that they are consistent when running on different machines or at different times. This can be done by having version numbers based on commit counts or the like.